# VSCode Lists Erroneous Apex Problems

Tags: apex, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

I'm using VSCode with Github and Deploying to a Sandbox. When I save my classes, VSCode lists problems which don't exist and which don't clear when the class is deployed successfully. For example, all custom objects are invalid types. I can deploy the class with no problems and I can paste it into the developer console for the default org with no problems reported. What do I need to do get VSCode to validate my Apex against my default org?

My settings.json:

```
{
  "salesforcedx-vscode-core.push-or-deploy-on-save.enabled": true,
  "search.exclude": {
    "**/node_modules": true,
    "**/bower_components": true,
    "**/.sfdx": true
  },
  "eslint.nodePath": "/Users/***/.vscode/extensions/salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode-lwc-46.10.0/node_modules",
  "editor.fontSize": 14,
  "salesforcedx-vscode-core.retrieve-test-code-coverage": true,
  "salesforcedx-vscode-core.show-cli-success-msg": true
}
```

Sample problems list:
[image]

Answer (score 11):

The issue was the `enable-semantic-errors` setting under Settings -> extensions -> Salesforce Apex. Unchecking this setting solved my problem. It's currently in beta. I hope this saves someone a little time.

Comment: Omg, I love you guy, I spent A LOT OF time on searching for the cause having over 500 errors like "variable does not exist" or "Object__c does not exist"... Thanks a lot that you shared this info here! Incredible that almost a YEAR later it still does not work...

Comment: Thank you @CleverLemming this resolved my issue

Answer (score 5):

You need to refresh your sObject definition cache. Select your project, go to the command palette (View > Command Palette), and type in "sobject". You should see an option called "SFDX: Refresh SObject Definitions". Using this feature will refresh your metadata definitions, and should remove the errors about "Invalid Types."

Comment: Still getting erroneous problems, but now new and different ones. For example, String externalID = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(hash).substring(0,18); yields "variable does not exist, EnclodingUtil." It's like I need Java package delcarations.

Comment: @Cleverlemming There's a typo in that name (EncodingUtil vs EnclodingUtil). That said, assuming it's just a typo here and not in your code, it might be a corrupt code cache or something. I just checked in my org's code and everything appears to be in order. Try creating a new project, building from a manifest, and/or updating all extensions and the CLI to the latest version. It should be working just fine.