# Errors in standard object definitions

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, vs-code, sfdx-plugin

I use VS Code with Salesforce Extension Pack.

- I have created SFDX project with manifest;
- authorized my sandbox org;
- then refreshed sobject definitions (tools-sobjects-standardObjects).

This gives me a bunch of errors in standard object definitions. For example:

```
global class Account {
    global List<AccountFeed> Feeds;  //--Invalid type account feed
    global List<AccountHistory> Histories;  //--invalid type AccountHistory   

    global List<CaseChangeEvent> Account;
    global List<NetworkSelfRegistration> Account;  //--Duplicate field:Account
 ...
}
```

I can see AccountFeed object in WSDL.xml file but its definition wasn't retrieved: there is no AccountFeed.cls in the standardObjects folder. Same with AccountHistory.

Or this:

```
global class Case {  //--identifier name is reserved: Case
    .... 
}
```

And there are weird errors like this in almost every object/class.

What all this means? These are all standard objects automatically retrieved from the ORG.
Is my VS Code configured incorrectly? It shows "Apex" at the bottom so I assume it recognizes this is Apex.

Is there a problem with Apex plugin? (I had trouble getting it to recognize Java versions from Oracle, but eventually AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.9.101-hotspot\ Worked and it doesn't complain anymore.)

Thank you for any input! I'm totally lost at this point.

Comment: Do the approaches mentioned in  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/274044/vscode-lists-erroneous-apex-problems help in fixing the issue?

Comment: @Swetha Thank you! It does remove squiggle lines :) I was hoping to fix the problem, not just hide it, but if this is all I can get so be it...

Comment: If you can elaborate on what other challenge you are facing, I can try to help.