# VSCode doesn't clear errors even after successfully deploying to org

Tags: apex, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

Since last week Friday my VSC is no longer clearing errors, even after I fix them. The only way to clear them is to close VSC and reopen it, which is a rather painful thing to do every time just to not be confused by the red lines and names :(

I have several VSC projects and have opened new windows with different projects in it, and they are all doing the same. I looked at this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/274044/vscode-lists-erroneous-apex-problems) from 3 years ago and attempted a new VSC project as suggested, but it made no difference. And enable-semantic-errors is *not* ticked, so it can't be that either.

Earlier last week I had none of these problems - has anything changed recently?
How do I get this fixed? Help please.

Below is a snip of the state I'm left in, even after the code has deployed it still has the class name in red, with the number of errors there and next to the Problems tab.

I have also cleared the VSC cache - still have the problem.

[image]
[image]

Comment: These problems are sometimes cached in VS Code and not cleared, but once you save them and deploy source to org, it is done right.

Comment: I auto deploy to org on save, as you can see on the snip, it has deployed the code and there are no more errors - it doesn't clear the errors, which is my problem.

Comment: @Irene, You can always right-click in the output panel and clear the output.

Comment: @MukulMahawariya clearing the Output panel does not remove the recorded errors from the Problems panel (or the name in red with #of supposed errors, which are no longer errors).

Comment: @Irene, can you share the screenshot of the problem panel and also can you try editing and saving the file?

Comment: @Irene I'm experiencing this problem as well. I'm developing on remote using WSL 2. sfdx-cli/7.204.6 wsl-x64 node-v16.13.0 @salesforce/cli/1.81.6 wsl-x64 node-v16.13.0

Comment: @MukulMahawariya I've added the Problem panel - it keeps the error that was there before I edited and saved (as the Output panel shows). The only way to clear it was to close VSC and open it again. This only started happening a week ago. Prior to that I didn't have these problems.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the error is - that is not the point. It's that it doesn't clear them after it deploys successfully. The Problem panel stays as it was at the error. It only adds additional errors if I create more. For eg I removed a curly brace which added 20 more errors to the Problems panel, yet when I reversed that and deployed again, the panel now shows 21 errors - the original one plus the additional 20 from the curly brace removal. It keeps adding to the errors the more I edit and create errors to test this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Take a look at this Github issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/4904). I was affected by this as well, and downgrading my Salesforce-related extensions to v57.15.0 worked for me

To downgrade:

1. Open VS Code
2. Extensions Tab
3. Search for 'Salesforce CLI Integration'
4. Click down arrow next to 'Uninstall'
5. Click 'Install Another Version...'
6. Select '57.15'
7. Reload VS Code

Comment: That did fix it yes, and I've gone back to that version now. I hope they fix the later version soon!

Comment: Thanks.  worked for me also

Answer (score 0):

## Update

This has now been resolved with v58.6.2 of the Salesforce Extensions for VS Code